# Export an org-mode file as a PDF via command line?

Tags: org-mode, init-file, org-export, beamer, batch-mode

What command-line arguments do I use to get Emacs to export an org-mode file to a Beamer PDF?  (I want to create a `Makefile` that produces a PDF when the user runs `make`.)

I tried following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22072773/712605) but couldn't get it to work:

```
$ emacs --batch foo.org -f org-beamer-export-to-pdf
Symbol's function definition is void: org-beamer-export-to-pdf
$ emacs --batch -l ox-beamer foo.org -f org-beamer-export-to-pdf
Cannot open load file: ox-beamer
```

The above error comes from the fact that the org-mode files are in a custom location and my `~/.emacs.d/init.el` is not loaded (`--batch` implies `-q` a.k.a. `--no-init-file`).

If I tell Emacs to load my init file it will work:

```
$ emacs --batch -l ~/.emacs.d/init.el foo.org -f org-beamer-export-to-pdf
```

However, this doesn't work for other users that use `~/.emacs` or `~/.emacs.el` instead of `~/.emacs.d/init.el`.  I tried telling Emacs to load `user-init-file` but it didn't work:

```
$ emacs --batch --eval '(load user-init-file)' foo.org -f org-beamer-export-to-pdf
Wrong type argument: stringp, nil
```

Assuming all users can successfully press `C-x C-e l P` to export a Beamer PDF when using Emacs interactively, what non-interactive command will produce a PDF?

Comment: eval `(require 'org)` or something like that – your init file is doing some loading that `--batch` is prohibiting.

Comment: Try something like `emacs -u $USER --batch --eval '(message "-----> My user-init-file: "%s" user-init-file)'`. If you don't load your init file, you probably need to require `ox-beamer`.

Comment: You might find https://github.com/fniessen/orgmk useful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```sh
emacs \
    -u "$(id -un)" \
    --batch \
    --eval '(load user-init-file)' \
    foo.org \
    -f org-beamer-export-to-pdf
```

Thanks go to @mutbuerger for the hint to pass `-u <username>` to get `user-init-file` defined.

Comment: In my case, I found that I needed to remove `(load user-init-file)` and replace it with specific `(require 'blah)` s-expressions for it to work (using emacs 24.5.1).

Answer (score 5):

I'm using self-compiled emacs 27.0.9x on Linux and macOS. To generate my presentations, I use org-mode.

```
emacs -Q \
  --batch "(require 'ox-beamer)" \
  <input>.org -f org-beamer-export-to-pdf
```

works for me.