# Display buffer from commandline

Tags: org-mode, latex

I'm trying to do the same thing as described in ([Export an org-mode file as a PDF via command line?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10392/export-an-org-mode-file-as-a-pdf-via-command-line)) generate a pdf from a org file but want to do it
inside a docker container also. And now I get an error and no pdf.
How do I display the content of the "*Org PDF LaTeX Output*"

The command I'm currently using is as follows:

```
docker run \
   -it \
   --rm \
   -v `pwd`:/docs \
   --entrypoint emacs \
   hgjt/emacs-texlive:latest \
   -l /root/emacs.el \
   --visit plot_var.org \
   --batch \
   --eval "(org-latex-export-to-pdf)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a sanity check, are you sure you have a tex distribution installed correctly? Maybe you can interactively load into your docker to test it out.

Here is a command which will dump the error log to a file named `Org-PDF-LaTeX-Output.err`:

```
emacs --visit plot_var.org --batch --eval "(progn (ignore-errors (org-latex-export-to-pdf))(set-buffer \"*Org PDF LaTeX Output*\")(write-file \"Org-PDF-LaTeX-Output.err\"))"
```